# null values stored in database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

I was wondering how are null values stored on DISK - is it allocating some minimum bytes - physical disk space as for other columns which have indeed some values and arranged contiguously as the rows are inserted into a table?

and a second question is: if the null values are updated with values, SQL will assign the space needed available at the end of the data file ?

thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Each row has a null bitmap for columns
>   that allow nulls. If the row in that
>   column is null then a bit in the
>   bitmap is 1 else it's 0.

Pardon me for linking to the [cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:6-iz751-JyYJ:weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/09/06/How_does_SQL_Server_really_store_NULL-s.aspx+sql+2005+%2B%2Bhow+are+null+values+stored%3F&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) version of the article from which that is taken.